# Multiple mouse position

Tags: python, mouse, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple piano keyboard for my programming class. I've made it in pygame because it's nice and simple to use. I've managed to get it working by making a mouse rect and individual rects for each note on the piano and having the note play by linking it to a mousebuttondown event. So it's working pretty good but I'll be demonstrating it on a smartboard and I was wondering if I could make it multiplayer. The problem is I can't work out a way that two people can play at the same time because obviously there's only one mouse (which is detected by the player tapping on screen) and therefore one mouse.get_pos() for the rect collision detection. If anyone can suggest a work around that'd be cool!

Thanks for the help

-Laura

Comment: you could simply send note played, instead of mouse position on the other computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Python based [kivy](http://kivy.org/) framework is emerging as an alternative to multiplatform multimedia application - and one of their proeminet features is the support for multi-touch. Of course your hardware (and drivers) will have to have multi-touch capbilities, but the Kivy framework can certainly deliver what you need on the Python side -

The alternative, without leaving Pygame, would be to emulate a second cursor that would be keyboard or game-controler controled - but it would require much more coding than simply detect the coordinates of a click.

Comment: Thanks for that help. I'd rather not use a keyboard or game controller if I don't have to but I will take a look into the kivy framework multi-touch stuff even if I can't use it for whatever reason. Just in case someone else comes up with a different answer I'll leave this up for the time being. Thanks again though! - Laura

Answer (score 1):

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has two attributes:

- pos
- button

If you use event.pos instead of mouse.get_pos() you should be able to pick up the coordinates where the click occurred even if you have more than one mouse.

Comment: That sounds awesome. I think I understand what you mean, I'll try it and see first :)

Comment: I'm curious, was this useful for you?